# My result of calculation takes 0 as the radius of convergence however the book says the radius of convergence is infinity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\left(\frac{\exp\left(2n\right)}{n!}\right)}_{a_{n}}x^{n}$$

$$a_{n}=\frac{\exp\left(2n\right)}{n!}$$

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{\exp\left(2\left(n+1\right)\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

$$=\frac{\exp\left(2n+2\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

$$=\frac{\exp\left(2n\right)\exp\left(2\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

To find out the radius of convergence of the given series, the following can be used.

$$R_{~\text{radius of convergence}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|a_{n+1}\cdot a_{n}^{-1}\right|$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\left(\frac{\exp\left(2n\right)\exp\left(2\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\exp\left(2n\right)}{n!}\right)^{-1}\right|$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\exp\left(2n\right)\exp\left(2\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{\exp\left(2n\right)}\right|$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\exp\left(2\right)}{\left(n+1\right)}\right|$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\exp\left(2\right)}{n+1}$$

$$=0~~\leftarrow~~~\text{My result}$$

But the book says the limit diverges to infinity.

Who is corret?me or the book?

Comment: Look up Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed. Radius of convergence $R$ is not $\lim_{n}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$(if the limit exists), but $\left(\lim_{n}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\right)^{-1}$!

So $R=\infty$, therefore this series converges regardless of the value of x.

Furthermore, we know $\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$, so can calculate your series.

$$\sum_0^\infty\left(\frac{\exp(2n)}{n!}\right)x^n=\sum_0^\infty\frac{(e^2x)^n}{n!}=e^{e^2x}.$$